# Picking out unique solution of $x,y,z$ from two constraints

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the conditions:$x+y+z=12$ and $x^3 y^4z^5=(.1)600^3$. Then the value of $x^3 + y^3 +z^3=?$

This is a question from JEE mains, in it I have a doubt of how we are able to uniquely determine an $x,y,z$ triplet from just two equations(upto permutation)! The answer involves observing $x=3, y=4 $ and $z=5$ but how can we make that inference?

Comment: A point to be made is, $x+y+z=12$ is symmetric in $x,y,z$ so it allows values of $x,y,z$ upto permutations but second equation $x^3y^4z^5=...$ is not symmetric, since the exponents are different. Hence maxima of $f(x,y,z)$ is not attained at permutations of $(3,4,5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive reals, we can use AM-GM inequality. This inequality for $12$ terms applies as

$$\frac{3\cdot (x/3)+4\cdot (y/4)+5\cdot (z/5)}{3+4+5} \ge \left(\frac{x^3}{3^3}\cdot \frac{y^4}{4^4}\cdot \frac{z^5}{5^5} \right)^{1/(3+4+5)}$$
$$\Rightarrow x^3\cdot y^4 \cdot z^5 \le 3^3 \cdot 2^8 \cdot 5^5$$
$$\Rightarrow x^3y^4z^5 \le (0.1)(600)^3$$

where equality (maximum) is achieved when each term is equal i.e.,
$$\frac{x}{3}=\frac{y}{4}=\frac{z}{5}=\frac{12}{12}=1$$

from which one infers $x=3, y=4, z=5$.

Comment: How do we prove that the answer is same for all other possibel solutions? Or is the one you wrote the only solution, if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by 'all possible solutions'? There is unique solution because $f(x,y,z)=x^3y^4z^5$ achieves maxima at single point namely $(3,4,5)$ (not even upto permutations).

Comment: @Buraian It's in the proof of AM-GM inequality that equality is achieved when each term is equal. This condition is being utilized to find the numerical value of $x,y,z$ uniquely. (See the simultaneous equation $x/3=\ldots=1$)

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but how does first line inequality imply the second line

Comment: I wrote it tersely. Note LHS is simply $1$.

Comment: Understood now, thank you ^^